# php preg_match_all: How to get aparat video id from URL?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the video id from aparat's URL with php preg_match_all;

Example Aparat URL formats:

http://www.aparat.com/v/3FJN0

I want to get "3FJN0"

?

Comment: any effort from your side?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following code.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.aparat.com/v/3FJN0';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$matches = preg_split("/\/v/", $path);
print_r($matches[1]);
```